# Dash sometimes stuck open; how to force it to close without logging out

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash, clementine

I've had a problem with the Dash bar in Ubuntu (11.04) Unity getting "stuck open". It happens when I'm dragging songs to a playlist in Clementine.

In any case, once it's stuck open, I haven't found any way to close it without logging out and logging back in. (I've tried going into about:config and changing the hide condition, but this doesn't help once the dash is stuck open).

So my question is: how to force the dash to close once it's stuck open?

[The issue itself is a bug in unity: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/769703 ]

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to press ctrl+alt+F1 to switch to a console. (By default you can choose to use F1-F6 for a console.) Then just log in and run:

```
unity --replace
```

That restarts all of unity, including the dash. Press ctrl+alt+F7 to get back to the desktop GUI.

Comment: It's easier to use Alt+F2 and type `compiz --replace`, if it works. If not, I usually open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `compiz --replace`, then do the Alt+F2 thing. (I do so twice to keep Compiz from running in a terminal window.)

Comment: Yeah, Scott's answer works quicker if your dash isn't frozen up. Which in Marco's case sounds like it wouldn't be. For me, dash usually freezes up, meaning that alt+F2 doesn't respond.

Comment: I haven't be able to get `unity --replace` to actually unfreeze the Dash. Unity restarts, but the Dash is still stuck open. What seems to work in my case is to force Clementine to close (by kill -9 'ing it).

Comment: Simple command `unity -v` worked for me.